# Is there a manual for JavaScriptCore shell (jsc)?

Tags: javascript

MacOS ships with a JavaScript shell `jsc` in the JavaScriptCore framework.  The easy way to run it from Terminal is to link it into a standard directory:

`ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Resources/jsc /usr/local/bin/jsc`

What built-in JavaScript functions does `jsc` support?

The [manual page](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC) documents some JavaScript functions like `readline()` and `run(filename)`.   But it's out of date — it's missing the command line options printed out by `jsc --help`.

I found the the [source code](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/jsc.cpp) to `jsc`.  It sets up more JavaScript functions.  Most of them look like testing and benchmarking hooks, but there some useful-looking functions like `read` and `print`.  Are they documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to the documentation.  It's merely a framework allowing you to run JavaScript from Swift, Objective-C and C based apps.

From [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore):

> The JavaScriptCore Framework provides the ability to evaluate
>   JavaScript programs from within Swift, Objective-C, and C-based apps.
>   You can use also use JavaScriptCore to insert custom objects to the
>   JavaScript environment.

The functions that are supported are referenced [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/javascriptcore_functions)